# Best way to keep the data up-to-date when dealing with web socket async request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-7

I'm seeking the best way to keep the data up-to-date when dealing with web socket async requests, especially data that contain `time` information.

I have a dashboard, when I logged/pressed  `feed` I updated the nextFeed time to `feedingInterval` + the current logged time.

feedingInterval = `2 hrs`

I used to do form submit, and page refresh.

Also, I used to do `location.reload()` every `1` minute to keep my nextFeed time up-to-date when my user opened up the link on a machine connected to a **TV**.

nextFeed time always up to date, worse case there is 1 mn lagged.

---

## NOW

***To enhance the UX:***

I don't use form submit anymore, so no page refresh, I use Ajax POST to a web socket route to broadcast to all my devices. When I receive any push notifications from Pusher Cloud, I update the DOM live dynamically on **all** my devices.

---

## Issue

I used to refresh my page every 1 minute, since I didn't do ( `location.reload();` ) anymore. My feeding time will become stale (not up-to-date).

***Current solution:***

I created an API to get the nextFeed time, called it every 5 seconds, and update DOM every 5 seconds. I notice my browser seem very hot since, maybe due too much requests in a minute.

Then you might say/think... just called every minute then ...

But ... If I make a call every one `1` minute then my users wont' have up-to-date information which defeats the purpose of me doing the websocket in the first place.

What should I do to have the best UX, but not too compromise my performance?

https://www.bunlongheng.com/baby/5db53c4c-5be4-4aa2-b9f6-b564acb871ac?code=d3s!gn

[image]

Comment: Honestly it sounds strange that "your browser get hot" when you push an update every 5 seconds, I built a chat application with laravel where it updates every second, not five, and it works just fine. I'd suggest that you check your Pusher APIs implementation, something sounds wrong.